Updating Multiple Node Values Using Template Match in XSLT
Input XML
<root>
    <Bank>
        <BankDetail>
            <Name1>BankName</Name1>
            <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
        </BankDetail>
    </Bank>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Text</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Text</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Text</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Text</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Text</Item1>
    </Item>
</root>

I want to update <Item1> node value with BankItem 1, BankItem 4, BankItem 2, BankItem 5 and BankItem 3
So the Output will be
<root>
    <Bank>
        <BankDetail>
            <Name1>BankName</Name1>
            <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
        </BankDetail>
    </Bank>
    <Item>
        <Item1>BankItem - 1</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>BankItem - 4</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>BankItem - 2</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>BankItem - 5</Item1>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Item1>BankItem -  3</Item1>
    </Item>
</root>

I have done this using the loop. But for learning purpose I dont want to use For Each loop. I want to update it by Template Match. Is there any way I can achieve this? Please suggest.
I dont have it working. I was trying couple of steps but then I felt I need some suggestion.
<xsl:template match="root/Item/Item1">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="Item1[$i]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
        
    </xsl:template>


Those numbers do not match the node's position, so you obviously cannot use Item1[$i]. Is there any logic by which the number could be calculated from the position, or is it completely arbitrary?

Its not the node position. its depends on some internal logic which results as different numbers with out sequence.

If you do not explain what that "internal logic" is then how can you expect anyone to come up with code that implements it?

Okay. Let me explain.
The actual input XML looks like



BankName
TestBank



Text 1


Text 2


Text 3


Text 4


Text 5


There is a C# code which is maintaining the mapping called as GetDataFromTextvalue(Item1 value)
With in that C# code the mapping is maintained as
Text 1 : Bank Item 1
Text 2 : Bank Item 4
Text 3 : Bank Item 5
Text 4 : Bank Item 5
Text 5 : Bank Item 3

So whenever there is a template match for Item 1 it will call that C# Code and will replace the text. I cant use a for loop here. The below sample will not work for this.

@User_Earth_005 Please edit your question and add these explanations there. Also explain how the C# code is passing the mapping to the XSLT stylesheet. If you have a working example using xsl:for-each, post it too.

One way to get the desired output would be:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item1">
    <xsl:variable name="i">
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>BankItem - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('14253', $i, 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

It's hard to tell if this meets your goal because the logic of the required transformation is not clear.

You want something like
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Item/Item1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="pf:GetDataFromTextvalue(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

where you need to adapt the pf to the prefix you use/declare for your C# extension function(s).
